# Facebook javascript SDK login https: works only if you login twice

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

*EDIT: please check the workaround at the end of this question.*

There are a lot of similar threads but I cannot find the same problem.
Basically, we moved our login page to HTTPS.
When the page was HTTP, everything was working great, without problems.
The flow was:

1. The user opens the login page
2. The user clicks on the Facebook login button
3. The user performs the FB authentication
4. The user is redirected to PAGE2

Now the flow is:

1. The user opens the login page
2. The user clicks on the Facebook login button
3. The user performs the FB authentication
4. The user is **redirected on the login page again!**
5. The user clicks on the Facebook login button
6. The user is redirected to PAGE2

So, the user has to perform the operation twice.

The code:

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({appId: HERE_MY_APP_ID,
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true});

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            if (response.status == 'connected') {
              // Something here
            }   
        }); 
    };  
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk';
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }   
        js = d.createElement('script');
        js.id = id; 
        js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
```

And this is the function called when the user clicks on the Facebook button:

```js
function fblogin() {
        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.status == 'connected') {
                login();
            } else {
                // user is not logged in
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }, {scope: 'email,publish_stream'});
        return false;
    }
```

Please note that debugging this code, the `response` printed in the `getLoginStatus` function says that `response.status` is `unknown` the first time, but when the page reloads, the response object is filled correctly, with `response.status` that is `connected`!.

How can I debug this issue? Any hints?

** WORKAROUND **
I've moved the `getLoginStatus` code from `fbAsyncInit` to the `FB.login` callback and now it works. But it's just a workaround, probably.

Comment: `all.js` is the old JS SDK, I’d recommend that you use the current version. Also, permission `publish_stream` is outdated as well. Go check the docs for what permissions are currently available.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, I completely agree that I will need to update my code. Anyway, in this case, on the same day the code with HTTP was working fine, with HTTPS no, so the issue should be somewhere else.

Comment: A possibility is that you are executing 'getLoginStatus' before the initialization completes, which is why your workaround works.